# RPM of wheels on touchdown

Tags: commercial-aviation, aircraft-physics, engineering

What is the average RPM of the wheels of commercial airplanes upon touchdown?

I understand there is variability that comes with different wheel sizes, approach speed, etc. Just thinking of the average RPM that the wheels almost instantly hit on contact.

Comment: At the instant of touchdown the wheel rotational speed is zero.

Answer (score 3):

For a 737 the tyres are 27 inches in diameter and landing speed is about 145 knots.  Converting to SI we have a wheel circumference of 2.15m and a speed of 75m/s so that equates to about 35 revolutions per second or just over 2000rpm.

Comment: +1 for SI Units

Comment: Is 27 inches the tire, or the rim?  Most American cars have >27" diameter tires.

Comment: @Harper that’s 27” tyre.  Back in the old days wheel diameters for cars were around 14 inches.  737 tyres are 27x7. 75 R15 but I suppose an operator could fit 205/55 R18 with some fancy mags and an appropriate STC.

Comment: It’s a thing, apparently.  https://www.dunlopaircrafttyres.co.uk/aircraft/boeing-737-next-generation-tires/

Comment: The nosewheel is 27" diameter.

Answer (score 2):

A typical heavy airliner has main tire diameters on the order of 50 inches, which works out to be a circumference of 157 inches, or about 13 feet.

A typical airliner might be moving at 125 Kts, or 12,500 FPM early in its ground roll.

The tire spins 1 rotation every 13 feet, so to cover 12,500 feet in one minute:

`12,500 / 13 = 955 RPM.`

Comment: Fair to say 737 tyres are relatively small so our estimates are probably towards the ends of the spectrum.